# Building an infinite range with range-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am trying to build a range which produces infinite random points in a triangle. To do that, I am using CGAL, which already provides the functionality to generate the random points in a triangle.

```
        Triangle coarseTriangle = {v[0], v[1], v[2]};
        CGAL::Random_points_in_triangle_2<Point> randomSamplesGenerator(coarseTriangle);
```

However, `CGAL::Random_points_in_triangle_2` returns an iterator. In order to produce a range, I need a sentinel which always return false. Is there any sentinel like that already in range-v3 or do I have to code one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::unreachable_sentinel`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/unreachable_sentinel_t) (Or [`ranges::unreachable`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1unreachable__sentinel__t.html) from [`<range/v3/iterator/unreachable_sentinel.hpp>`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/iterator/unreachable_sentinel.hpp)):

```cpp
        ranges::subrange randomSamplesRange(randomSamplesGenerator, ranges::unreachable);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, but G wasn't helping

Comment: Actually, is not working. subrange() fails to be built and make_subrange fails due to missing `is_sized_sentinel_`